# Copying all Lines from One file to other file in a Fair Random Manner in Big O(n) running time complexity

Tags: arrays

you have a file with multiple string lines and u have to put it into another file in fair random manner, how would you implement it with linkedlist and array only given as constraint.
the distribution should be random i.e. should not follow any pattern which is guessable i.e. round-robbin or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FairRandomDistributionDataFromOneToOtherFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Driver Program to read the lines into the String Array.
         FileReader fr = null;
         LineNumberReader lnr = null;
         try {  
            
            // Please Pass the File Path to the below filereader to run this program
             
            fr = new FileReader("/home/sgarg/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.10.0.RELEASE/Interveiw/src/com/sunil/stringfile");
            lnr = new LineNumberReader(fr);
            lnr.mark(500); // some random read ahead limit, I just choose 5000 randomly
            lnr.skip(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            int totalLines = lnr.getLineNumber();
            String[] data = new String[totalLines];
            // resetting to mark, basically start of the file
            lnr.reset();    
            for (int i=0; i<totalLines; i++) {
                data[i] = lnr.readLine();
            }

            shuffleAndWriteDataToNewFile(data);
            
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      
        
    }
    
    /**
     * @param data    - All lines of the files read and passed as String into this String[] 
     * 
     */
    public static String[] shuffleAndWriteDataToNewFile(String[] data) {
        int len = data.length;
        int rand= 0;
        for (int i=0; i < len; i++) {
            // choose the next random number between the all current valid lines
            rand = getNextRandomNumber(len - i);
            // Now whatever the random line we get, we will move it to the end of the array and assume that 
            // next random number generator will generate random lines from 0 to len - i 
            swapLine(data, i, rand);
            // this way our random lines getting settled in the last index of the array which keeps decrementing with loop iteration
            // this way we dont need to take a 2nd array to store the lines and complexity vise it is an O(N) solution as we are iterating 
            // over the array once.
        }
        
        return data;
    }
    
    /**
     * Swap two String Objects in the given String Array.
     */
    public static void swapLine(String[] data, int curr, int rand) {
        int len = data.length;
        String temp = data[len-1 - curr];
        data[len -1 -curr]  = data[rand];
        data[rand] = temp;
    }
    
    public static int getNextRandomNumber(int numOfElements) {
        return (int)(Math.random() * numOfElements);
    }
    
}
```